# How to create bitbucket account with free off cost, for a group of four members

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to create bitbucket account for group of four members, for free off cost. I have created account in bitbucket, but I am not getting how to create account for free off cost. Anyone please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already created your account. Your colleagues will need to create their own accounts, if they haven't already. Once their accounts exist, you should be able to grant them access to your repositories.